# Improve performance postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables: `users`, `posts` and `likes`. A post is called *hot post* if it has more than 5 likes within the first hour after post creation. The following is using to query for a list of hot posts. Can anyone help me to improve this query (how to index or rewrite it).

```
SELECT post.id,
       post.content,
       user.username, 
       COUNT(like.id)
FROM posts AS post 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS user
      ON post.user_id = user.id 
   INNER JOIN likes AS likes
      ON post.id = likes.post_id
         AND likes.created_at - INTERVAL '1 hour' < post.created_at
GROUP BY post.id, user.username
HAVING COUNT(like.id) >= 5
ORDER BY post.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it works. http://prntscr.com/hidlsc

Comment: You need to provide more information for anyone to provide you with any valuable insight. For example, your table definitions, any existing indexes (if any), and the output of the `EXPLAIN`. Additionally, try not to give table aliases with capital letters and remove all double-quotes (for readability).

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

First, unless there really can be a post that does not belong to a user, use an inner join there.

Assuming that there is a good number of posts and likes, the best join strategy would be a merge join or a hash join, which PostgreSQL should choose automatically.

For a merge join, the following indexes might be helpful:

```
CREATE INDEX ON posts (id);
CREATE INDEX ON likes (post_id);
```

No index could help with a hash join in this case.

If the planner chooses a nested loop join after all, it might be useful to rewrite the query to:

```
... AND likes.created_at < post.created_at + INTERVAL '1 hour'
```

and create an index like

```
CREATE INDEX ON likes (post_id, created_at);
```